# 'freezing' mongoose subdocs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have setup similar to:

**B.js**

```
var schemaB = new mongoose.Schema({
  x: Number,
  ...
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('B', schemaB);
```

**A.js**

```
var schemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
  b: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B'},
  ...
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('A', schemaA);
```

With this, changes can happen to my `B` documents, and when I retrieve my `A` documents using [populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), those changes will be reflected in the object at path `b`.

However, is there someway to "*freeze*" the document at path `b` of a particular `A` document? Something like:

```
var id=1;
A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
  if (err) return handleErr(err);

  console.log(a.b.x);
  // prints 42

  a.freeze('b') // fictitious freeze() fn
  b.x=20;

  b.save(function(err, b) {
    if (err) return handleErr(err);

    console.log(b.x);
    // prints 20

    A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
       if (err) return handleErr(err);

       console.log(a.b.x);
       // prints 42

    }); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context I'm not totally sure why you need to. It seems like the problem should maybe be looked at from a higher level?

One thing I do know about is the [toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) function. It strips away the Mongoose metadata and logic and leaves you with a plain JS object. This object won't change unless you change it. You could then add this object onto `a` as a separate property from `b`.

```
// A.js

var schemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
    b: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B'},
    frozenB: {}
    ...
});
```

---

```
// app.js

var id=1;
A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
    if (err) return handleErr(err);

    console.log(a.b.x);
    // prints 42

    a.frozenB = a.b.toJSON(); // Creates new object and assigns it to secondary property

    a.save(function (err, a) {
        b.x=20;

        b.save(function(err, b) {
            if (err) return handleErr(err);

            console.log(b.x);
            // prints 20

            A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
                if (err) return handleErr(err);

                console.log(a.frozenB);
                // prints 42

            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

---

### Edit - If you need `frozenB` to be a full mongoose document then just do the same thing but make it a new document.

```
// A.js

var schemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
    b: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B'},
    frozenB: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B'}
    ...
});
```

---

```
// app.js

var id=1;
A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
    if (err) return handleErr(err);

    console.log(a.b.x);
    // prints 42

    var frozenB = a.b;
    delete frozenB._id; // makes it a new document as far as mongoose is concerned.
    frozenB.save(function (err, frozenB) {
        if (err) return handleErr(err);

        a.frozenB = frozenB;

        a.save(function (err, a) {
            b.x=20;

            b.save(function(err, b) {
                if (err) return handleErr(err);

                console.log(b.x);
                // prints 20

                A.findById(id).populate('b').exec(function(err, a) {
                    if (err) return handleErr(err);

                    console.log(a.frozenB);
                    // prints 42

                });
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I like that approach! The only downside being that I wouldn't be able to use any of `B`'s getters/setters/virtuals ect on `frozenB`. The reason for this is ... my `A`'s depend on lots of external data that is highly volatile, changing hourly (the `B`'s). However, I need to be able to take _snapshots_ of my `A`'s and persist them indefinitely.

Comment: See my edit. All you need to do is assign `b` to a variable without calling `.toJSON()`, delete the `_id` property, save the new document to the database, and then add the new document to `a.frozenB` and save `a`.

Comment: Hmm. The only problem is now I'm polluting my `B` collection. I think I'd do something similar to this, but have auxiliary `FrozenB` collection that I create using the same schema used to create the `B` model - then I can dump frozen objects in there..

Comment: I read the first sentence of your reply and started typing "What about a FrozenB collection?" Then I read the rest of your reply. lol

Comment: You'll want to do something like `var frozenB = new FrozenB(a.b.toObject());` I think.

Comment: No problem. PS - The difference between `toJSON()` and `toObject()` seems to be that `toObject()` returns the inner MongoDB object that mongoose wraps. That means it will contain fields on the document that may not have been part of the schema (by default mongoose documents don't show any properties not part of the schema). `toJSON` doesn't do this. It just returns a plain object with only the properties from the mongoose document. Also, both methods accept an option to include getters and/or virtuals in the resulting object.